# Angular with Web API ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-500

I am trying to use Angular-8 with WebAPI-2 but getting error with 500 status code. Tried the same service code with ASP.Net MVC and is working fine.

> **Web API Code:**

**TestController.cs**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("Hello from test web api");
}
```

> **Angular code:**

**test.service.ts**

```
export class TestService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getTestMessage(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5638/api/test');
  }
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  testMessage: any;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.getTestMessage().subscribe(
      testMessage => {  
        this.testMessage = testMessage;  
      }
    );
  }
}
```

> **ERROR:**

```
GET http://localhost:5638/api/test 500 (Internal Server Error)

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:5638/api/test", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: I recommend debugging the API and make the same request, then see what exceptions or other errors occur on the server side.

Comment: Matt, already tried but no error with output: "Hello from test web api"

Comment: You debugged while hitting the endpoint from your Angular front end?

Comment: Tried from Angular front end and got error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED [http://localhost:5638/api/test]
ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:5638/api/test", ok: false, …}

Comment: What error is shown in the API when running the debugger and sending the request from Angular? You'll need to start the API with the debugger in Visual Studio or whatever IDE you use, then make the request from Angular.

Comment: No error from the API side but got above error from Angular side

Comment: The ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED often means the server couldn't be contacted on the specified port. Make sure 5638 is the correct port for the API.

Comment: Yes port is correct and tried again but with an error from Angular front end. No error from API end. (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) [http://localhost:5638/api/test]
ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:5638/api/test", ok: false, …} )